# nginx cannot serve .php files from reverse proxy

Tags: php, nginx-reverse-proxy

On reverse proxy machine (http://rp-server) the nginx configuration files is as follows:

```
location ^~ /path/ {
    proxy_pass http://upstream-server/;
}
```

And all requests asking for static files such as .jpg .js .txt etc works like a charm:

http://rp-server/path/anyfile.jpg -> http://upstream-server/anyfile.jpg

But for .php files it reports 404 error.

http://rp-server/path/install.php should be http://upstream-server/install.php but actually something like the local fastcgi on **rp-server** tries to handle it instead and certainly there is no such thing as http://rp-server/path/install.php so it reports 404. That's what I read from the log files - the request never reaches **upstream-server**.

So what should I try next?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm dealing with a similar problem, having nginx reverse proxy php requests to an apache server upstream.  Also- do you understand what that regex is doing, for the location?  Anything requests that aren't to /path/ will be proxied.  Have you tried putting in a proxy directive for `location ~ \.php$` ?  maybe it has to be done explicitly.

Comment: Not yet found a solution. I am reading your explanation.